# PayPal Hosted Fields re-render on every state change react-paypal-js

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm having a problem where doing any state change will re-render the PayPalHostedFields. If I enter the viable data into the paypal hosted fields, and then do any state change the component will re-render and clear out the hosted fields.

How do you do state management for hosted fields without re-rendering the script-provider every time?

```
<PayPalScriptProvider options={{
                            'client-id': process.env.REACT_APP_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID || 'test',
                            'data-client-token': token,
                            components: 'buttons,hosted-fields',
                            currency: currency
                        }}>

                            
                        <PayPalButtons 
                            fundingSource={"paypal"} 
                            style={{ color: "gold", shape: "rect", label: "paypal", height: 40 }}
                            forceReRender={[price, currency]}
                            createOrder={createOrder}
                            onApprove={onApprove}
                            onCancel={onCancel}
                            onError={onError}
                        />

                        <div className="paypal-hosted-fields-container-div" style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
                            <PayPalHostedFieldsProvider
                                styles={{
                                    ".valid":{"color":"#28a745"},
                                    ".invalid":{"color":"#dc3545"},
                                    "input":{
                                        "font-family":"monospace",
                                        "font-size":"16px"
                                    },
                                }}
                                createOrder={createOrder}
                                onCancel={onCancel}
                                onError={onError}
                            >

<div className='ch-pay-radio_div'>
                                        <div
                                            className='ch-pay-radio-shipping-address-first'
                                            onClick={checkCheck}
                                        >
                                            <input
                                                type='radio'
                                                name='ch-radiogroup'
                                                defaultChecked={true}
                                                style={{ marginLeft: '8px', marginTop: '0px' }}
                                                checked={!checked}
                                            />
                                            <label
                                                className='ch-pay-radio-ship'
                                                style={{ marginBottom: '0px' }}
                                            >
                                                PayPal
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div
                                            className='ch-pay-radio-shipping-address'
                                            onClick={checkCheck}
                                        >
                                            <input
                                                type='radio'
                                                name='ch-radiogroup'
                                                defaultChecked={false}
                                                style={{ marginLeft: '8px', marginTop: '0px' }}
                                                checked={checked}
                                            />
                                            <label
                                                className='ch-pay-radio-ship'
                                                style={{ marginBottom: '0px' }}
                                            >
                                                Card
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [the documentation example](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/paypal-paypalhostedfields--default), using your own credentials and replacing the fetches with your dynamic `token` value and own createOrder function

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
    PayPalScriptProvider,
    PayPalHostedFieldsProvider,
    PayPalHostedField,
    usePayPalHostedFields,
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

const CUSTOM_FIELD_STYLE = {"border":"1px solid #606060","boxShadow":"2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"};
const INVALID_COLOR = {
    color: "#dc3545",
};

// Example of custom component to handle form submit
const SubmitPayment = ({ customStyle }) => {
    const [paying, setPaying] = useState(false);
    const cardHolderName = useRef(null);
    const hostedField = usePayPalHostedFields();

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (hostedField) {
            if (
                Object.values(hostedField.getState().fields).some(
                    (field) => !field.isValid
                ) ||
                !cardHolderName?.current?.value
            ) {
                return alert(
                    "The payment form is invalid, please check it before execute the payment"
                );
            }
            setPaying(true);
            hostedField
                .submit({
                    cardholderName: cardHolderName?.current?.value,
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    // Your logic to capture the transaction
                    fetch("url_to_capture_transaction", {
                        method: "post",
                    })
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((data) => {
                            // Here use the captured info
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            // Here handle error
                        })
                        .finally(() => {
                            setPaying(false);
                        });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    // Here handle error
                    setPaying(false);
                });
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <label title="This represents the full name as shown in the card">
                Card Holder Name
                <input
                    id="card-holder"
                    ref={cardHolderName}
                    className="card-field"
                    style={{ ...customStyle, outline: "none" }}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Full name"
                />
                </label>
            <button
                className={`btn${paying ? "" : " btn-primary"}`}
                style={{ float: "right" }}
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                {paying ? <div className="spinner tiny" /> : "Pay"}
            </button>
        </>
    );
};

export default function App() {
    const [clientToken, setClientToken] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const response = await (
                await fetch(
                    "https://braintree-sdk-demo.herokuapp.com/api/paypal/hosted-fields/auth"
                )
            ).json();
            setClientToken(response?.client_token || response?.clientToken);
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {clientToken ? (
                <PayPalScriptProvider
                    options={{
                        "client-id":
                            "AdOu-W3GPkrfuTbJNuW9dWVijxvhaXHFIRuKrLDwu14UDwTTHWMFkUwuu9D8I1MAQluERl9cFOd7Mfqe",
                        components: "buttons,hosted-fields",
                        "data-client-token": clientToken,
                        intent: "capture",
                        vault: false,
                    }}
                >
                    <PayPalHostedFieldsProvider
                        styles={{".valid":{"color":"#28a745"},".invalid":{"color":"#dc3545"},"input":{"font-family":"monospace","font-size":"16px"}}}
                        createOrder={function () {
                            return fetch(
                                "your_custom_server_to_create_orders",
                                {
                                    method: "post",
                                    headers: {
                                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                                    },
                                    body: JSON.stringify({
                                        purchase_units: [
                                            {
                                                amount: {
                                                    value: "2", // Here change the amount if needed
                                                    currency_code: "undefined", // Here change the currency if needed
                                                },
                                            },
                                        ],
                                        intent: "capture",
                                    }),
                                }
                            )
                                .then((response) => response.json())
                                .then((order) => {
                                    // Your code here after create the order
                                    return order.id;
                                })
                                .catch((err) => {
                                    alert(err);
                                });
                        }}
                    >
                        <label htmlFor="card-number">
                            Card Number
                            <span style={INVALID_COLOR}>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <PayPalHostedField
                            id="card-number"
                            className="card-field"
                            style={CUSTOM_FIELD_STYLE}
                            hostedFieldType="number"
                            options={{
                                selector: "#card-number",
                                placeholder: "4111 1111 1111 1111",
                            }}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="cvv">
                            CVV<span style={INVALID_COLOR}>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <PayPalHostedField
                            id="cvv"
                            className="card-field"
                            style={CUSTOM_FIELD_STYLE}
                            hostedFieldType="cvv"
                            options={{
                                selector: "#cvv",
                                placeholder: "123",
                                maskInput: true,
                            }}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="expiration-date">
                            Expiration Date
                            <span style={INVALID_COLOR}>*</span>
                        </label>
                        <PayPalHostedField
                            id="expiration-date"
                            className="card-field"
                            style={CUSTOM_FIELD_STYLE}
                            hostedFieldType="expirationDate"
                            options={{
                                selector: "#expiration-date",
                                placeholder: "MM/YYYY",
                            }}
                        />
                        <SubmitPayment customStyle={{"border":"1px solid #606060","boxShadow":"2px 2px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"}} />
                    </PayPalHostedFieldsProvider>
                </PayPalScriptProvider>
            ) : (
                <h1>Loading token...</h1>
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: My problem is I want to have radio buttons in the hosted field provider so that the user can choose between paypal and cards, but changing the radio button state causes a re-render which clears the card details. I will edit the question with my radio buttons.

Comment: Do you have to do it with radio buttons? It's possible to render just a paypal button, the word "or" centered, and the credit card form.

Comment: I want to do it with the radio buttons as users will have to choose between using the same billing address as shipping address as well. So there are other things on the page besides just the hosted fields no matter what